# Installing ActiveGraph on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, neo4j

I am trying to install ActiveGraph on Rails to integrate neo4j into my application.  I am running on the Mac with Ruby 3.2.2 and Rails 7.1.3.  Bundle Install seems to be working fine but when I run the application it get the following error:

```
"...rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support/per_thread_registry (LoadError)"
```

Not even sure where to start.

Comment: https://github.com/neo4jrb/activegraph/issues/1702

Comment: Thanks, Alex!  Running with ActiveGraph 11.5.0 beta 2 and 2 fixes the problem!

Comment: Scott, I am trying to get Rails (similar versions to you) to connect to neo4j, and while I'm past the thread error you posted, I get a failed connection (pasted below) trying to do anything (the browser instance does work at port 7474).

`(Neo4j::Driver::Exceptions::ServiceUnavailableException)`
`Connection refused - connect(2) for [::1]:7687 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)`

Was hoping you might be able to point me in the right direction.